# Destroying stream cause destroying the bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream

I have something like:

```
       public Bitmap GetBitmap()
       {         
            Byte[] byteArray= bring it from somewhere    
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                return new Bitmap(stream);
            }
        }
```

When I use this method outside the Bitmap is crushed. but if I stepped into the "using" scope the bitmap will be exists and works fine. it seems that disposing the stream cause disposing the bitmap..
the question is:
Do I need some deep copy? how should I perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dispose the `Bitmap` will be lost, so indeed you need so perform a deep copy.
Eventually your code should be:

```
public static Bitmap GetBitmap()
{
    byte[] byteArray = bring it from somewhere
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
        return new Bitmap(tempBitmap); // This will deep-copy the Bitmap
    }
}
```

By the way, usually primitive types, like `byte` are written in small case.